# What makes Julia unsuitable for general purpose programming?

Tags: programming-languages, julia

I really like the Julia language. It's designed for scientific computing but looks like a pretty good general purpose language to me. What (if anything) makes it unsuitable for general purpose programming (e.g. web apps)? Lack of libraries is the obvious one but is there something more "unfixable"?

Comment: I am not familiar with Julia, but the usual issues with trying to use a special-purpose language to write general-purpose programs are 1) appropiate IO facilities (user/presentation, disk/file and DB), 2) adequate integration with the Host OS facilities, 3) build deployment packaging, and 4) project structuring and modularty.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

There is no reason not to use Julia for general purpose programming. Julia is a counterexample to the premise that technical computing languages (e.g. Matlab, R) cannot also be suitable for general purpose computing.

Comment: With the caveat that other languages might be *better* for general-purpose programming. I'd not want to use R for essentially all non-data-crunching programming, for example.

Comment: I'm not claiming that R is good for general purpose programming, but that Julia is. The point is that R isn't bad at general programming *because* it's good at statistics – it's badness for general purpose programming is an incidental artifact of the fact that its designers didn't care about using for that those kinds of things. We very much care about the quality of Julia for general programming.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood (read: completely missed) the "counterexample" part.